# Swift - Use of unresolved identifier

Tags: swift, scope, identifier

I create all the variables within the same function. But at the end of the function I can't reach the constant even though it was created in the same function.

When I write "self.resultLabel.text = weather" at the end, Xcode shows me an error use of unresolved identifier 'weather'

I know how to fix it. I need to initiate 'weather' just after the task method starts and set it to "" and then I should change its value in the function but even if I don't do it and I create it in the if closures, shouldn't I be able to reach it while within the same function?

I don't understand why it keeps me giving this error.

```
func findWeather() {

        var errorStatus = false

        city = (cityField.text?.stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet()))!

        let url = NSURL(string: "http://www.weather-forecast.com/locations/" + city.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "-") + "/forecasts/latest")!

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let content = data {

                let urlContent = NSString(data: content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
                let weatherContent = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")
                if weatherContent.count > 1 {

                    let weather = weatherContent[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")[0].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: "˚")


                } else {

                    var weather = ""
                    errorStatus = true

                }


            } else {

                var weather = ""
                errorStatus = true

            }


            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in

                if errorStatus == true {

                    self.showError()

                } else {

                    self.resultLabel.text = weather // I get error: use of unresolved identifier 'weather'

                }

            })

        }

        task?.resume()
```

Comment: Move `var weather = ""` to before the `if let`. This is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 1):

You're defining too many new variables `weather` which are all visible only locally between the curly braces they are in.

The best place to define `weather` is at the beginning of the `task` closure and all `var` or `let` declarations of the subsequent occurrences of the variable have to be deleted.

Here the crucial part:

```
 let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

    var weather = ""
    if let content = data {
      let urlContent = NSString(data: content, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding) as NSString!
      let weatherContent = urlContent.componentsSeparatedByString("<span class=\"phrase\">")
      if weatherContent.count > 1 {
        weather = weatherContent[1].componentsSeparatedByString("</span>")[0].stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("&deg;", withString: "˚")
      } else {
        errorStatus = true
      }
    } else {
      errorStatus = true
    }

...
```